# MongoDB uses COLLSCAN when returning just _id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I want to return all IDs from a MongoDB collection and I used the code below:

```
db.coll.find({}, { _id: 1})
```

But MongoDB scans the whole collection instead of reading the information from the default `index { _id: 1 }`.

From the log:

```
{ find: "collection", filter: {}, projection: { _id: 1 } } 
planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:30463374118 keysExamined:0
docsExamined:544783 numYields:4286 nreturned:544782 reslen:16777238
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 8574 } }, Database: {
acquireCount: { r: 4287 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 4287 } }
} protocol:op_query 7024ms
```

Any idea how to fix this, please?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you using? Since you haven't specified any query criteria or sort order, the fastest plan for iteration is generally (but not always) a collection scan in natural order. See [SERVER-23406: index scan is slower than full collection scan in some scenarios](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23406) and linked issues for background details. Adding a sort order or hint on `_id` should result in a covered index query with your projection. For comparison, can you try: `db.coll.find({},{_id: 1}).sort({'_id':1})`)?

Comment: Stennie, thanks `db.coll.find({},{_id: 1}).sort({'_id':1})` really works! 

Also `.hint({_id: 1})` works as you suggested in other comment:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor.hint

Answer (score 3):

You would need to add a filter that can use this index like so in order to change that query plan - not all operations remove the FETCH stage, e.g. $exists does not appear to work:

```
db.coll.find({ _id: { $ne: 0 }, { _id: 1 }) // works for ObjectIds
```

One part of the explanation for this is in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query):

> A covered query is a query that can be satisfied entirely using an
>   index and does not have to examine any documents. An index covers a
>   query when both of the following apply:
>
> - all the fields in the query are part of an index,
> - and all the fields returned in the results are in the same index.

I seem to remember seeing a JIRA request to support that without the filter but cannot remember which ticket that was...

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, `$exists: true` does not skip the FETCH phase, which reads all documents from the collection.

Comment: True. I was only looking at the log output to see if the index was used and not the full execution plan...

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution, which works if one knows the type of the `_id` field. In case of string `_id`:

```
db.coll.find({ _id: { $regex: ".*" }, { _id: 1 })
```

In case of integer `_id`:

```
db.coll.find({ _id: { $gte: 0 }, { _id: 1 })
```

Comment: You could also use `sort({_id:1})` or `hint()` as I suggested in a comment on the question.